# Not defined error in console while passing php value to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am passing PHP value to AJAX but I am getting an error that variable is not defined.

```
$value_r is not defined
```

When the user selects the checkbox then the value of $value_r will auto display.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name=value_r]").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/compare.php", // 
               data: {id: <?php echo '$value_r'?>},
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**index.php**

```
<input  type="checkbox" value="" name="value_r" id="value_r"/>
<label for=""><?php echo $value_r?></label>
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type=checkbox] + label{
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$value_r`?

Comment: That values will come from PHP. I mean If any user selects the check box than $value_r will display.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `$value_r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error here.

Change

```
data: {id: <?php echo '$value_r'?>},
```

to

```
data: {id: '<?php echo $value_r ?>'},
```

Regards!

Comment: That's correct. I need one more help. How to display the value of $value_r because I tried $abcu=$_POST['id']; but it is not displaying

Comment: Can you help me in about doubt. Because I have to display the value on other page $abcu=$_POST['id']; is not working

Comment: OK, first check -console.log(value_r )- just after call the ajax and see the value. second, in your php do a echo $abcu; before setting the post['id']

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=value_r]").click(function(){
        var value_r = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/compare.php", //
            data: {id: value_r},
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Then How can I display the id value to another page because  I tried $abcu=$_POST['id']; which is not working